# Remote script execution using ssh timeout after 10 minutes

Tags: ssh

I am trying to execute the remote shell script on a linux machine from another linux machine using **SSH**

It works perfectly fine for most of the cases, however I have a script which is has inactivity of more than 10 minutes, my connection to remote machine is lost.

**Remote Shell Script**

test.sh

```
echo "testing"
sleep 3600
echo "done testing"
```

And this is How I am calling this script

```
➜  ~ ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3600 -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no gaurang.shah@host_name /home/gaurang.shah/test.sh
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*          Unauthorized use of this system is strictly prohibited             *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

testing
Connection to host_name closed by remote host.
```

Shouldn't this parameter keep the connection alive for 3600 seconds ?

> -o ConnectTimeout=3600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConnectTimeout` specifies the timeout (in seconds) used when connecting to the SSH server

You have to set `ServerAliveInterval` instead. To set it for all users you have to modify `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (having root grants). To enable just your user modify `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 3600
    ServerAliveCountMax 2
```

If you can modify the server side, you can make your server keeps alive all connections with clients by adding the following to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ClientAliveInterval 3600
ClientAliveCountMax 2
```

Comment: what worked for me is `ssh -v -o ServerAliveInterval=600 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2` as I guess from server side ClientAlive is 600 seconds. setting `ServerAliveInterval` more than 600 is not working